# Why Google Speed insights & Google Lighthouse & Web.Dev showing different audit results for the same url?

Tags: performance, google-chrome-devtools, google-pagespeed, lighthouse

Why Google Speed insights & Google Lighthouse & Web.Dev showing different audit results for the same url?

Although I’m using the tools that’s based on Lighthouse! ( Google speed insights - Web Dev - Speed insights API- Lighthouse/Chrome Dev Tools)

I’m auditing the same url: https://www.mindvalley.com/uncompromised-life/masterclass/invite

**using Google speed insights**

- Mobile Score 59%
- Desktop Score 86%
  [image: Google speed insights Mobile]

[image: Google speed insights Desktop]

**using Web.Dev**

- Performance 65% 
  [image: Web.Dev Results]

**On Lighthouse using Chrome Dev tools**

- performance 29%

[image: lighthouse Chrome Dev Tools]

What makes me confused is that I’m automating the auditing for our funnels using lighthouse api and it's giving me different performance number from all the numbers above!

I read the documentation: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/get-started

I tried the CURL

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=https://www.mindvalley.com/uncompromised-life/masterclass/invite
```

And I’m getting the score **95%** so I’m confused between the different values for the same audit metric

**I have 2 questions:**

1. How to get the mobile score “The number on Google speed insights” using the Google speed api “ https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=landingpage_url” ?
   1.1 Currently I’m using PHP to get the score and I’m parsing the auditing results as follow: `$audit_encode->lighthouseResult->categories->performance->score;` but It’s giving me different number
2. What’s the best number I can rely on it for the mobile performance auditing? We want to focus on optimising for mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. add `&strategy=mobile` to your request string to get the mobile scores.
2. As long as you use the same method each time it doesn't matter. What is more important than the score is looking at the things it recommends to improve so as long as you use a consistent testing method it doesn't matter. `lighthouseResult->categories->performance->score` is the correct score to use if you check using the parameter in answer 1 (multiplied by 100 of course as it will return a decimal out of 1)

You are getting 95% on the API as it defaults to desktop, you are getting slower speeds on local as you are probably running 'Applied Slow' vs 'Simulated Slow'

Comment: Thank you so much @Graham Ritchie The api working now and get the audit according to the mobile strategy audit! 
 
@ mobile strategy audit "64%" almost the same of Web.Dev 

I asked the 2nd question as I want to setup a benchmark for +30 funnels and automate the performance QA for it so It would be great to explain to other stackholders what exactly this number means and when I'm comparing to the lighthouse score "29%" it's huge difference but I'll go and read the documentation of the lighthouse I think I don't know the best way to config the auditing! 

Thanks, That helps me a lot :) .